# Make field as invalid until i set it as valid in angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, directive

I have a input field when it is invalid i make its border as red when it is invalid. I am using below code in directive for some regex and once regex is passed i need to do some more validation.

```
  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event.target.value'])
    onKeyup(value) {
        // this.validateFormControl.markAsTouched();
        if (value) {
            let result = this.regex.test(value);
            if (!result)
                this.control.control.setErrors({
                    'pattern': true
                })
            }
        }}
```

But what happens is that, when user starts entering field becomes valid and then invalid because of test. This makes the border to go blue and red. How to prevent field become valid during this event. I know i can use patterns but i need to do 2 levels of validation on field. It should just behave like how it behaves in case of patterns.

Please try input 12.4443333 and start removing numbers from right side, you can see green border coming and immediately red border appearing.

https://plnkr.co/edit/CLNUv3dhPmHtlhIa8kjU?p=preview

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: Make invalid until I set it as invalid.. Sound like it'll always be invalid!

Comment: Updated question with plunk code.

Comment: But if the value is valid, shouldn't the border indicate that until the entry is invalid, just like it does now? What you are saying is even though the entry is valid show it as invalid. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: If i try using same in pattern way, flickering effect is not seen. If i implement on my own the Flickr is seen.